# Percentage data with many 100 values

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, interaction, random-variable, zero-inflation

I am looking at the accuracy percentage that has a distribution with several $100%$ values. These are true $100%$ values since most people have high accuracy in some conditions. Here is the distribution of the variable:
[image]

I want to model the accuracy as the outcome variable with Condition (condition 1, condition 2 and condition 3), Scale (scale 1, 2, 3, 4) and Trial Number (1 to 4) as the predictor variables with random effects of participant ID, sex and age.

Accuracy is calculated as a "score" obtained by following correct sequence in a game. If an individual followed the entire sequence correctly, the accuracy score was 100.

My questions are:

1. Is it alright to use `lmer` instead of `glmer.nb` (negative binomial) despite the high number of $100$ values?
2. I have been getting a singular fit warning and I am assuming I am over-fitting the model. However, I am not sure how to choose what random effects to drop and why?
3. I am interested in the interaction effect of condition and scale but the data is too small to test this. What is a way around it?

The model looks something like this:

```
model_accuracy <- lmer(accuracy.perc. ~ Cond + Scale + trials_nb + (1|participants) +(1|session) + (1|age), data = data)
```

Comment: Why not model the binary outcomes that underlie the accuracy? That's a pretty obvious approach (that also deals nicely in case denominators differ between people) and then you can use random effect logistic regression e.g. using `lme4::glmer`.

Comment: If the possible scores are just so many out of 10, then model that directly. The reference distribution is then as said binomial, not beta, and certainly not normal. However, it is surprising that 90& or 9/10 is so rare, regardless of  protocol. That may imply measurement oddities that are awkward or impossible to model -- or possibly some mixture of participants.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146875/discussion-on-question-by-stats-what-percentage-data-with-many-100-values); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.